# Is there a way to change the text color of an item in a ListView when it is selected?

Tags: android, listview

I'm working with Android Studio.

I have an activity that creates a list of items as follows:

```js
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_listado_categorias);
        inicializarControles();
        ....
    }
```

Where:

```js
private void inicializarControles() 
{
...       
  m_itemCategoria = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.act_item_listview);
  m_lvwCategorias = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvwCategorias);
        
  m_lvwCategorias.setAdapter(m_itemCategoria);                        
  
  
  m_lvwCategorias.setOnItemClickListener(onItemCategoriaListViewOnClickListener);
m_lvwCategorias.setOnItemLongClickListener(onItemCategoriaListViewOnItemLongClickListener);
  
        
  m_lvwCategorias.setOnDragListener(onItemCategoriaListViewOnDragListener);
....
}
```

The onDragListener event is currently running successfully.

My question is:

Is there a way that when I select an item from the list it can change the color of the text? (Only selected item)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your child views to:

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

Now you can use the methods to declare your TextViews' colors using a selector such as:

```
android:textColor="@drawable/my_row_selector"
```

and I'm sure you're aware, but the selector can be as simple as:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/white" />
  <item android:color="@color/black" />
  </selector>
```

As you can see, @color values are allowed. Also - android:state_pressed is used in conjunction with the AdapterView.OnItemClickListener. Hope this helps.

or you can try this,

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > adapterView, View rowView,
int position, long id) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowListTextView);

    textView.setTextColor("Desired Color");

}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Yes. By using a color selector.

Under your `res` folder in you app project create a directory named `color`. In this color directory add a XML file (eg., color_selector.xml).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/COLOR_WHEN_PRESSED" />
    <item android:color="@color/COLOR_NORMALLY" />
</selector>
```

Your color_selector.xml should look like this.

Then in your xml file where you declared your view that contains text. Set the android:textColor attribute to this selector. Like so:

```
android:textColor="@color/color_selector"
```

You may also declare textColor programmatically by:

```
    TextView text;
    text.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.choose_alarm_color_selector));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Color Selector file in your drawable folder, let's say you name it "text_selector.xml", then paste this code in that file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true"
       android:color="#000000" /> <!-- pressed -->
 <item android:state_focused="true"
       android:color="#000000" /> <!-- focused -->
 <item android:color="#FFFFFF" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Now you just simply have to set the set the color of your textview in your "act_item_listview.xml" file with this selector file like this:

Define a property in your textview object:

```
android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
```